# How to get Channel Name for Video, youtubeAPI, Python

Tags: python, youtube-api

Firstly the previous "answer" to a similar question used the deprecated Youtube Api V2. Also none of the answers showed how you can do it with Python.

My code is:

```
def youtube_search(item):


  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=item,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=6
  ).execute()


  videoCount = 0;
  title = ""
  channelId = ""
  channelName = ""
  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videoCount += 1
      if videoCount == 1:
         snippet = search_result["snippet"]
         title = snippet["title"]
         channelId = snippet["channelId"]
         channelName = snippet["channelTitle"] 

#  print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
  print( item, videoCount, title, channelId, channelName )
```

So essentially from the first returned video I want to know the title of the video and the name of the channel. It is the name in particular I am looking for. For this search string:

```
r'''"Joe Keegan" "Pick Myself Up"'''
```

My result is:

```
('"Joe Keegan" "Pick Myself Up"', 1, u'Pick Myself Up', u'UCThUpINg-JADDOHdkz_4-jw', u'')
```

The Channel Name I am looking for here is "Various Artists - Topic". In particular I have a huge list and am trying to eliminate any with that channel name (which is a lot). There are however a lot of channel ids that use that name. channelTitle doesn't give me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

While all this was going on I was trying to solve it myself and have merged a few other answers around the place to come up with a solution that works. It might not be the best one so please if you have a better one let me know. But it may be useful here for others who stumble across trying to do the same:

Essentially I did a URL "Get" request on the video id and parsed the JSON response. Oh, Python is such an easy language to use sometimes...

```
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videoCount += 1
      if videoCount == 1:
         snippet = search_result["snippet"]
         title = snippet["title"]
         videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"] 
         channelId = snippet["channelId"]

  urlBase = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
  if videoCount > 0:
     url = urlBase + videoId + "?v=2&alt=json"
     r = requests.get(url)
     metadata = r.json()
     channelName = metadata["entry"]["author"][0]["name"]["$t"]

print( item, videoCount, title, channelId, channelName )
```

And of course I don't really need channelId...

Comment: It works for me at the moment. I find the documentation for v3 very poor. A few code samples which is fine if that's exactly what you want to do but when you want to do something slightly different it doesn't show you where to get the data.

The good thing about http request / JSON response is that it's easy to just print the JSON you get and see if it contains what you're looking for. So once you know what request to make, you can find what you want. 

youtube suffers a problem that is historical and not fixed in that it doesn't have proper metadata tags.

Comment: When you upload a video to youtube it would be good if, when you picked the category of music video you filled in proper fields for artist name, title and ideally you'd also indicate whether it is a motion video or an audio, but that could be auto-detected.

Comment: i agree - i went a different route to pull info from all the videos from a user and get the metadata , especially viewcounts : but I used your code as a guide using v2 still. so karma for you!

Comment: I used opencv to try to detect if it's a video or an audio and it does a reasonable job though not perfect.